# Practical NFT handling in wallets

Tags: nft, account, wallet, associated-token-account

Each non-native token (all except SOL) needs a dedicated token account to handle it.
It means that:

- either NFT buyer need to inform NFT seller where to send the NFT (in case of HD wallets for instance, where such address would be a derived address)
- or the minter create the account on behalf of buyer and sends private key to buyer (highly unsecure).

There must be another way.
Seems it is the Associated Token Account, where address is (deterministicly) derived from buyer main account + NFT mint address (and program address), so minter only needs buyer address to send the NFT, and buyer only needs NFT mint address (and program address) to see it in it's wallet.

If all above is correct, it does not hide the fact that, if I buy 1000 NFTs from a collection, I will end up with 1000 accounts.
How such multitude of accounts is handled by wallets ? Especially in case of migration (you change your wallet) ?